# Making my dictionary comprehension more efficient

Tags: python

I have a list of strings. For example:

```
lst = ['aa bb cc', 'dd ee ff gg']
```

Each string in the list is known to contain 2 or more whitespace delimited tokens.

I want to build a dictionary keyed by the last token with the first token as its value.

The following dictionary comprehension achieves this:

```
d = {e.split()[-1]: e.split()[0] for e in lst}
```

This gives me:

```
{'cc': 'aa', 'gg': 'dd'}
```

...which is exactly what I want.

However, this means that the element *e* will have its *split()* function called twice per iteration over *lst*.

I can't help thinking that there must be a way to avoid this but I just can't figure it out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `map`:

```py
d = {v[-1]: v[0] for v in map(str.split, lst)}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`walrus`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) operator. But list comprehension is not meant to efficient, it's just shorter(I think)

```
lst = ['aa bb cc', 'dd ee ff gg']

d={j[-1]:j[0] for i in lst if (j:=i.split())}
print(d)
```

Comment: Assuming they are using python 3.8, that is.

Comment: If you're using the walrus operator, it makes more sense to write `d = {(j := i.split())[-1]: j[0] for i in lst}` rather than abuse an `if` clause like this.

Comment: No. Because for this input `lst = ['', 'dd ee ff gg']`  code will not work. That's why I keep it in this way

Comment: At the time I wrote the comment, you had `if (j := i.split()) or True` which had the same problem; that's what I described as an "abuse" because the `if` condition would never be false anyway. That said, the version I wrote *will* work in the case you wrote, in the sense that it will have exactly the same result as the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a function it would be much cleaner as you are carrying out an additional instruction, not just creating a list. Since you are looking to create a single holder of split values you will need to ensure there is some way to access index `0` or `-1`.

But it can be done like so:

```py
d = {e[0]: e[-1] for e in [item.split() for item in lst]}
```

Should work for you.

> Updated answer for python 3.8 +

I just recalled a recent addition on this. You can also achieve this without the inner comprehension:

```py
d = {parts[0]: parts[-1] for e in lst if (parts := e.split())}
```

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to other answers, you can make use of unpacking to get rid of the indexing, IF the elements in your list are always going to have **at least 2 strings separated by spaces** (which as you say, they do), otherwise this won't work:

```py
d = {last: first for first, *_, last in map(str.split, lst)}
print(d)
# {'cc': 'aa', 'gg': 'dd'}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, all the other answers, as well as this one, also execute `split` only once per string. The only difference is that this one unpacks the result, but I'd say the difference is mostly aesthetic.

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the question but found an interesting way to do this -

```
dict(map(lambda x: (x[-1],x[0]), map(str.split, lst)))
```